# Cocos2d-iphone v3 - draw a line and convert it so I could use it for CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, line, ccsprite

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjZBq.png

Right I've looked and I can seem to find the answer.

I'm using Cocos2d-iphone V3.

What I want to achieve is the above.
I want to take the devices width or height and and draw two lines.
I want to take the drawn lines and use the for the CCProgress.

Question:
How do I take the drawn lines and convert them to CCSprite?

If you can give me the code it would be great, but if you could give me a link to any tutorial or documentation so I can learn how to do this, that would be even better.

Thank you.

@LearnCocos2d

So i'm doing this now but I get a very weird result;

CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

```
_progressWidth = winSize.width *2;

//CGPoint position = ccp(0.3, 0.5);
//CCTime interval = 1.0/60.0;



NSMutableArray * tempProgressFg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[Utilities getRows]+1];
NSMutableArray * tempProgressBg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[Utilities getRows]+1];

CCTexture * bg = [_progressBg texture];
CCTexture * fg = [_progressFg texture];
for (int i = 0; i < [Utilities getRows]; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        _progressBg.scaleX = _progressWidth;
        _progressFg.scaleX = _progressWidth;
        _progressBg.position = ccp(0, i * TILE);
        _progressFg.position = ccp(0, i * TILE);
        [tempProgressFg addObject:_progressFg];
        [tempProgressBg addObject:_progressBg];
    }
    else
    {
        CCSprite * tempBg = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:bg];
        CCSprite * tempFg = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:fg];

        tempBg.scaleY = 1;
        tempFg.scaleY = 1;

        tempBg.scaleX = _progressWidth;
        tempFg.scaleX = _progressWidth;
        tempBg.position = ccp(0, i * TILE);
        tempFg.position = ccp(0, i * TILE);

        [self addChild:tempBg];
        [self addChild:tempFg];
        [tempProgressBg addObject:tempBg];
        [tempProgressFg addObject:tempFg];
    }
}
```

The result that i get is in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7WUr.png

1. is the _progressBg and Fg;
2. are the tempBg and Fg (multiples of them);

I want to have them all look like number 1.

Am I doing something wrong? is that the correct way to coppy the bar?

Comment: use regular images, 2x2 in size and solid color, then stretch (scale) the images to make up the bar. Far easier and faster than drawing lines onto a sprite/texture.

Comment: how can I scale it according to a certain width or heigt?

Comment: desired width / image width = x scale factor .... same for height/x. Example: 100/2 = scale factor 50 to enlarge 2x2 image to 100x100

Comment: So far so good, now i'm running into a problem of trying to copy the texture and apply it to the other progress bars... Not sure what's going wrong! Really appreciate the help Thank you!

Comment: sorted now thank you, your answer lead me to find it :)